# Why don't these agile carousels work properly in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been using Agile Carousel for a while now and it worked completely in the past, but has stopped working in Safari and Chrome, but is working on Firefox and Safari for iPad.

On [this page](http://www.1aproductions.co.uk/awards.html), the carousel stops at the second image and I just can not work out why.

On [this page](http://www.1aproductions.co.uk/home.html) again the carousel stops on the second image, but the problem is intermittent and if you pause the carousel and the start it again the problem 
disappears!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Additional info:

here's the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("Carousel/agile_carousel_awards.php", function(data) {

        $("#flavor_1").agile_carousel({
            carousel_data: data,
            carousel_outer_height: 478,
            carousel_height: 478,
            slide_height: 480,
            carousel_outer_width: 300,
            slide_width: 300,
            transition_time: 1200,
            timer: 4000,
            continuous_scrolling: true,

        });
    });
});

</script>
```

I'm beginning to wonder if the problem is not with the code at all, but with my laptop. It's worked when I tried it on another device.

Is the problem of it pausing in the second image happening on there folks systems?

Thanks again!

Comment: The code works in chrome console, try to put the carousel js code before the body close tag, I think that you have that code in the middle of the page and carrousel css in the head tag.

Comment: Have no problem on the second page on chrome... Please add the faulty code to your post

Comment: I've added the code to the original post.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome on my desktop, and the first link stopped at the second image. The second link was fine.

Comment: Second page works fine for me; could you give us some system details? I am using Chrome 28.0.1500.72 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Hi - I have Mac OS 10.8.4 Safari 6.0.5, Chrome 28.0.1500.71, Firefox 3.6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a couple of my websites.
Upgrading jQuery to version 2.0.3 fixed it for me.